# Difference between these regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regular expression that matches numbers from 1 to 100.

This works:

```
var regNumeric = /^(100|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])$/;
```

But this does't

```
var regNumeric = /^100|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]$/;
```

Why?

Code:

```
var value = '121' ;
var regNumeric = /^(100|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])$/; 
if(regNumeric.test(value)){
  // Match 
  }
```

Comment: **How** are you using this regex ? In what language ? Show the relevant code.

Comment: The first uses a logical OR `(a OR b OR c)`. W/o the parenthesis, this won't work.

Comment: you could check those two expressions at an online rexex tester like https://www.debuggex.com/ (which will show you the difference - look at the anchors!)

Comment: Google: **Regex 101**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why this works?

- `/^(100|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])$/`

Because of the parentheses it will apply start `^` and end `$` anchors to each of the pattern separated by OR `|`.. which is equivalent to.. `^100$` or `^[1-9][0-9]$` or `^[1-9]$`

> Why this doesn't?

- `/^100|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]$/`

This regex is equivalent to `^100` or `[1-9][0-9]` or `[1-9]$` (observe the anchors). So this would match unnecessary requirements like `100abc` or `hey13s` or `batman5`